# Find and Replace with Regex in Microsoft Word 2013

Tags: regex, string, replace, ms-word

I am editing an e-book document with a lot of unnecessary markup. I have a number of sections in the text with code similar to this:

```
<i>Some text here</i>
```

I am trying to run a regex find and replace that will find any phrase between the two i-tags, remove the i-tags, and apply a style to the text.

Here is what I'm using to search:

```
Find: (<i>)(*)(</i>)
Replace: \2
```

I'm also selecting Styles > i (for italic). This tells our conversion software to apply italics to the text. If I leave the i-tags, what ends up happening is ScribeNet's conversion process converts them to hex-values so that they show up as literal text in the e-book. Messy.

When I run this search, I get no results. I have "use wildcards" checked. What am I missing? According to Microsoft's help website, * is used to represent any number or type of characters, and individual strings are supposed to be enclosed in parentheses.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To search for a character that's defined as a wildcard, place a backslash (`\`) before that character. The `*` itself matches any string of characters, so use the range quantifier to match (`1` or more times)

```
Find: \<i\>(*{1,})\</i\>
Replace: \1
```

Answer (score 14):

Search for `\<i\>(*{1,})\</i\>` and replace with `\1`. Don't forget to check `Use wildcard`.

There is a reference table for Word's "regular expressions" here: https://web.archive.org/web/20140209231503/http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/word-help/find-and-replace-text-by-using-regular-expressions-advanced-HA102350661.aspx

- `<` and `>` are special characters that need to be escaped
- `*` means any character
- `{1,}` means one or more times

Comment: @Vache Thanks for your help as well. hwnd had the answer in before you so I felt it was only ethical to give him the green check, but as soon as I have 15 reputation I'll upvote both of your answers! :) Have a wonderful day.

Comment: For anyone else looking for how to do regex in Word, the link above is helpful, but nowhere on that page is any kind of comprehensive table. Here is the table -- I found it. I'm posting so it may save some of you the time and frustration i keep running into looking for a `comprehensive` regex reference. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295435.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: @EricHepperle-CodeSlayer2010 That is a regex reference for a different tool (Expression Web) and I don't think Word supports all of it. For example, it doesn't seem to support matching the start of a line, or the pipe character.

Comment: @Chris Thanks. Yes, I realized recently that exact thing. Bummer. The best solution I have come up with is to `use a text editor like Notepad++ that allows full Regex substitution` and get your text all set before pasting in Word. Or, copy parts of a Word doc into said text editor and do your regex operations. The downside is you may lose some of your formatting when you paste it back in. A neat tip I discovered is that you can search and replace a non-linked url in Word with a hyperlink globally using `^c` in the "Replace with box".

Comment: I have to amend my previous statement, you can sort of match the start of a line, by matching the end of the previous line. [This page](https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/General/UsingWildcards.htm) has more details, but basically you can match some characters with a string like ^13 (this is the end-of-paragraph mark).

Comment: Thanks @Chris... Your link is worth a full answer. I leave it up to you.

Comment: @SalathielGenèse maybe, but it's not an answer to this question. Might do a question-and-self-answer I guess.

Comment: Remember that if you are not in USA you may have a different **culture** set in Windows. Word unfortunately changes wildcards according to Office settings, so "one or more times" will become `{1;}`  (notice the semicolon)

Answer (score 0):

There is a special tool for Microsoft Word called Multiple Find & Replace (see http://www.translatortools.net/products/transtoolsplus/word-multiplefindreplace) which allows to work around Word's wildcard limitations. This tool can use the standard regular expressions syntax to search and replace any text within a Word document. For example, to search for any HTML tags, you can just use <[^>]+> which will find opening, closing and standalone HTML tags. You can add any number of expressions to a list and then search the document for all of them, replace everything, see all matches for all the search expressions entered, replace only selected matches, and a few more things.

I created it for translators and editors, but it is great for any advanced search/replace operations in Word, and I am sure you will find it very useful.

Stanislav