# How to enclose found text in LaTeX-environment using MS Word search & replace?

Tags: search, replace, ms-word, latex, wildcard

I'm working on a project where I have to convert Word documents to LaTeX. One of the problems I have right now is that I want to replace all italic text passages with the text passage enclosed in the corresponding LaTeX evironment. In order to to this, I am trying to use wildcards. So for example something like this:

**Search:**
(<*>)

**Replace:**
\textit{\1}

**Example:**

*test* -> \textit{*test*}

Now there are a few issues with this example. First of all, <*> only looks for words but I would like to find whole text passages. I haven't found out how to do that yet. In the replace field, Word always complains about the usage of the '\' character. I simply cannot put it there. I have read that you need to use it to exclude wildcard characters, so I tried to use two subsequent ones, but that still doesn't work.

This is the first time I am using wildcards so I really have no clue. I googled around quite a bit already (which is how I found this site by the way), but I just don't know how to do it.

Comment: Have you first read all of the replies to: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27731/how-can-i-convert-from-microsoft-word-to-a-latex-document

Comment: It's unclear whether you're trying to do this in Word or in some other program? If Word, then you can't use Regular Expressions. Word has its own "wildcard search" patterns and you must use those. Display the "Advanced" find dialog box, click the "more" button, then the Special button (the list will change if wildcards is activated). If you need more assistance on how to use these, search the Internet - there's a lot of material out there.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply!

I haven't read that conversation but thanks for pointing it out. Unfortunately it's not really what I am looking for.

Yes, I'm trying to do this in Word 2013 and I know about the wildcard search which is what I was already using. As I said I already searched the internet quite a bit but the commands I found there (the official ones) aren't working or I couldn't find what I was looking for. So I was hoping for somebody with experience in this field who could help me out

Comment: In that case, please edit your question to NOT use the term "regular expression" as that is NOT the same as Word wildcards and will be misunderstood by anyone with knowledge about how to work with Word's Find and wildcards

Comment: Please explain how "Word always compalins about the usage of the \ character". What's the exact wording of the message?

Comment: Ok I see. I thought it was the same. As I said this is the first time I am doing this I didn't even come up with the term myself. In fact it took me some time to find out that these would be called regex (or not after all). I used the term because among others I found it being used on this website http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24308538/find-and-replace-with-regex-in-microsoft-word-2013 and also the official Office website calls it regex: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Find-and-replace-text-by-using-regular-expressions-Advanced-eeaa03b0-e9f3-4921-b1e8-85b0ad1c427f

Comment: Sorry if that was confusing. I edited the original question.

Comment: About the error code: It's a bit hard for me to translate but here is my best take on it: "The text in the field 'replace by' includes a group number which is outside of the allowed range" Now "group number" is really just a literal translation I guess this could be a technical term and thus hard to translate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use wildcards or a macro. Indeed, you don't even need to specify the 'Find' text. All you need to is an ordinary Find/Replace in which you specify Font:Italic as the Find parameter and, for the Replacement text, use: \textit{^&}

Comment: Wow, this actually works! Thank you! May I ask why you can use wildcard expressions in the replacement text even if you didn't check the box to activate it? What am I missing here?

Comment: @mapf The '^&' replacement expression has nothing to do with wildcards; it is the standard Word Find/Replace expression for including the found text in the replacement. There's a whole raft of such expressions, which you can see by expanding the Find/Replace dialogue and clicking on the 'Special' button - there's different ones for both Find and Replace.

Comment: I see, thank you. This is really good to know. I never read about this anywhere. I feel like these options are poorly documented.

Answer (score 1):

After sorting through your question multiple times I finally believe I understand what you're asking and the answer is that you can't do it with Find/Replace alone.

It is possible to find all contiguous text ranges formatted as italics using Format/Font and selecting italics. This can be done without wildcards and it will select all contiguous text (multiple words) with this formatting.

Your problem comes at the point where you want to put something "around" what you've found. This is only possible when searching specific terms. As soon as you use a placeholder such as * you can only replace what's found - it can't be re-used. So at this point macro code is required.

The following example searches italics and at that point Find stops. The codes before and after are then inserted around the found range, the range to search is reset and the action loops until no more instances of italics are found.

```
Sub FindReplaceLatex()
    Dim rngSearch As word.Range
    Dim rngFound As word.Range
    Dim sBefore As String, sAfter As String
    Dim bFound As Boolean

    sBefore = "\\textit{"
    sAfter = "}"
    Set rngSearch = ActiveDocument.content
    rngSearch.Find.ClearFormatting
    rngSearch.Find.Font.Italic = True
    Do
        bFound = rngSearch.Find.Execute(wrap:=word.wdFindStop, Format:=True)
        If bFound Then
            Set rngFound = rngSearch.Duplicate
            rngSearch.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
            rngSearch.End = ActiveDocument.content.End
            rngSearch.MoveStart wdCharacter, 1
            rngFound.InsertBefore sBefore
            rngFound.InsertAfter sAfter
        End If
    Loop While bFound
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow that is amazing! Thank you so much! It's sad to hear that this is not possible to do by default with Word. I actually thought that this was an easy thing. It's a bit disappointing to be honest. Especially since I know this now: In Open Office this works in fact by default! In the search bar you put format italic and the line ".*" (without the ") and in the replace bar you put "\\textit{&}". This actually works. Nevertheless I'll try and see if I can implement your code :)

Comment: Since I posted yesterday I did come across something that makes it ALMOST possible. I did find out how it can work word-by-word. In case it helps now or in the future, with wildcards: Find "<(*)>" Replace "^92^92textit{\1}" . The parentheses in Find define an "expression" that can be re-used in Replace. ^92 specifies the ANSI character (backslash). \1 is the re-used expression from Find.

Comment: Wow yes this almost does it! This is really close. Unfortunately I would need the whole italic passage to be replaced/enclosed by the textit command but thanks again for the effort you put into it!