# RegEx does not work in MS Word

Tags: regex, ms-word

I'm trying to find all expressions like "6B_479/2013" or "6B_17/2014" in MS Word. Using the (regex101.com says correct expression)

```
[0-9]{1}[A-Z]{1}[_]{1}[0-9]{2,3}[\/][0-9]{4}
```

does not work in Word...

Can anyone help me?

Simon

Comment: Maybe this helps you: [Find and Replace with Regex in Microsoft Word 2013](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24308538/find-and-replace-with-regex-in-microsoft-word-2013)

Comment: See: http://superuser.com/questions/890288/how-can-i-do-find-and-replace-with-regex-on-microsoft-word

Comment: What version of Word are you using?

Comment: FYI, wildcards are not the same as regexes, so testing them on sites like Regex101 is not helpful.  And like regexes, wildcards come in different flavors; you can't reliably test MS Word wildcard expressions anywhere but in MS Word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try again:

```
[0-9][A-Z]_[0-9]{2;3}/[0-9]{4}
```

Tested with Word 2016 (German). Extended Search. Option for wildcards ("Platzhalter") checked.

The separator for the range operator seems to be locale dependent.
I need to use a semicolon (;) while a comma (,) is the more common variant.

Comment: I suspect the semi-colon is the list-separator character in your regional settings?  Mine is a comma (USA).  Interesting.

Comment: Ahh, with the semicolon it works great unter Word 14.0. (swiss/german locale). Thx!