# can you use regex within a MS Word link to a file?

Tags: regex, ms-word

Is it possible to incorporate regex into a MS Word code link to other files?

I am tasked with delivering a daily report with images which are always saved at the same directories, but whose names may change slightly depending on the day. These file names may contain "KPIR" or "KPIE" depending on how they are generated, and "48h" or "72h" depending on which day of the week they were generated.

My current report features links in this form:

```
{ INCLUDEPICTURE Z:\\Daily_Reports\\Inputs\\KPI\\KPIR_48h_combined_world.png \* MERGEFORMAT }
```

But when the names change, I must manually change all the links in the word file and revert this the following day, hence my interest in using regex within the code link.

Some other threads hint that regex should be possible in MS Word, e.g. [RegEx does not work in MS Word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39750583/regex-does-not-work-in-ms-word). Thus, I tried to replace KPIR in that link by KPI[A-Z] , KPI[E,R] , KPI? and also KPI* but none of them worked; and similarly for the 48h vs 72h, I tried [0-9][0-9]h , *h , ??h , (\")(\d{2})(\")h , and also (\d{2})h with no success.

Does anybody know the trick to this? Many thanks!

Comment: This question does not meet stackoverflow guideline though and should be asked in superuser forum.

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not possible. You can only link to an explicit filename. Instead of changing the links, you might consider setting up a process that renames the received images.